# Check the file extension on selecting a file for 'file_field' and show error messages (if there are) using Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, prototype

I am running Ruby on Rails 3 and Prototype and I would like to check the file extension on selecting a file for `file_field`, so I can show an error if it is not one of those that are permitted (in my case only `.doc` and `.pdf` are permitted extensions).

At this time in my view file I obseve the `file_field` in this way:

```
page.event.observe('file_field_id', 'change') do |element|
  # Here I would like to put some code in order to check the file extension
  # If the file extension isn't '.doc' or '.pdf' I would like to set and show an error text in the 'error_id'
  # I know using 'element[:error_id].show' I can show the error, but...
  #   1. how to set the error value?
  #   2. how to check the file extension?
end
```

Now I need to check if, after selecting a file, the string in the `file_field` have the exention `.doc`or `.pdf` and if no, set a value for the `error_id` and show it.

**How I can do that?**

---

**UPDATE**: I need that using the `Protoype` framework. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS, by using regular expression you can get file extension.

```
var extens=(/[.]/.exec(myfile)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(myfile) : undefined;
```

Here `myfile`is the address or the path  of the file. This simply takes the part of the string after "." . Then you can place some control checks with `if`. Something like :

```
if(extens=="doc" || extens=="pdf")
{
       //your method goes here
}
else
{
       error_id= ........
}
```

Comment: It must be possible. Try and find out

Comment: I tried it but without success, otherwise I didn't post the question! lol